# How to remove object (including components) from arraylist?

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a task planning app. I have a 'new task' button to add a task. When clicked, this button makes a new instance of the TaskRowToDo class and adds this to the toDoList arraylist. This class contains a row with a text field and some buttons.

This is the 'new task' button code:

```
private void drawNewBtn(){
    JButton btnNew = new JButton("Nieuwe taak");
    btnNew.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("New task added");
            toDoList.add(new TaskRowToDo(toDoIndex+7, false, "new task", 2));
            toDoList.get(toDoIndex).draw();
            toDoIndex++;
            frmPlanner.revalidate();
        }
    });
    frmPlanner.getContentPane().add(btnNew, "cell 3 12");
}
```

At the end of the TaskRowToDo there is a 'remove' button. This button should remove the row from the toDoList and remove this row from the screen.

Below is the 'remove' button code:

```
btnRemoveToDo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("To Do removed");
                toDoIndex--;
                toDoList.remove(toDoIndex);
                frmPlanner.revalidate();    
            }
        });
```

The button removes the instance of TaskRowToDo from the toDoList, but it still shows up on screen and the components even work. So it's not really removed. I've tried using revalidate() and repaint() but to no avail. As a test I tried frmPlanner.removeAll() and even this doesn't clear the screen (however the components won't work anymore).

How do I remove this one row, including its components and clear this space on the screen?

Comment: Checkout your code to github or somewhere, otherwise it doesn't seem that clear for anyone.

Comment: @РоманГуйван No! The question should be posted with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: Give some more code, because I don't know what type is toDoList, TaskRowToDo, frmPlanner.

Comment: Should I post all my code? I don't think it works anymore if I take it apart.  toDoList is an ArrayList (containing TaskRowToDo objects), TaskRowToDo is a class (containing three buttons, a textfield, a slider and a date picker), frmPlanner is a JFrame (the application window)

Comment: *"Should I post all my code?"* No, do what the link I posted tells you to do.

Comment: TaskRowToDo is class extending JPanel? Try call `repaint()` on frmPlanner or use some trick: 'frmPlanner.setVisible(false); frmPlanner.setVisible(true);` should heps.

Answer (score 1):

toDoList is JList?
give same more code, on this time I suggest to setModel on JList.
I always prepare method setModel when I create JList and it works:

```
    private void setModelForJList() {
    toDoList.setModel(new ListModel<TaskRowToDo>() {

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return toDoListEntityList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public TaskRowToDogetElementAt(int index) {
            return toDoListEntityList.get(index);
        }
        @Override
        public void removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        }
        @Override
        public void addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {
        }
    });
    toDoList.repaint();
}
```

when you delete object from JList, call this method, toDoListEntityList is list of object which you put in Jlist.

About JList some advices. Good practice is declare generic type of JList (in your case is  `JList<TaskRowToDo> toDoList= new JList<TaskRowToDo>`

Comment: toDoList is an ArrayList. I've never heard of JList, is it comparable to ArrayList?

Comment: JList is component of Swing library. On your question is Swing tag